# Problems with mixed 802.11b/g/n

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, 802.11

So my home network is currently set up to be 802.11b/g/n (2.4Ghz, 20Mhz), but I have some issues with it. Pretty much all devices work without any problem, except my phone. The Wi-Fi connection on my phone is painfully slow.

So if I set up my network to be 802.11n only, then my phone works like a charm, as well as most of the other devices in the house. The problem is that I must have a b/g/n network, because some older devices that I use don't support 802.11n.

So the dilemma is to have 802.11b/g/n and have my phone slow down, or have 802.11n only, but then some devices will not be compatible with my network.

The slowness is definitely not caused by overlapping with other networks. I checked on that, and it appears that one of my neighbors uses channel 1, and the other uses channel 6. There are no other wireless networks in my area. I set up my router to be on channel 11, so according to [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/2.4_GHz_Wi-Fi_channels_%28802.11b%2Cg_WLAN%29.svg/1700px-2.4_GHz_Wi-Fi_channels_%28802.11b%2Cg_WLAN%29.svg.png), overlapping should not happen at all, since this is pretty much the perfect setup channel-wise.

So are there any solutions to this?

Comment: One option would be to get a cheap AP that supports 802.11g and add it to your network, and have a separate SSID for those devices that only do g.

Comment: I happen to have a bunch of routers around, so I could easily fire one up and do that. I will try, thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is idiosyncratic to the original poster’s setup and not relevant to others.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. Even though the only two other Wi-Fi networks in the area are on channel 1 and 6, my network was still overlapping something on channel 11. Maybe not a Wi-Fi network, but god knows what (many other devices use 2.4Ghz not just Wi-Fi). So I set my router on channel 4 (b/g/n), and suddenly my phone had fast Wi-Fi again.

But this is still a bit strange... so if there was clearly some overlapping, then why didn't any of my other devices slow down? It only affected my phone, which is very weird. Anyway, I'm now happy on channel 4 :)